# How to fix UnsatisfiedLinkError for tesseract in android

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract, tess-two

i am trying to use "tesseract" for android
i am using following libraries

> ```
> compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:tesseract:3.04.01-1.3'
> compile 'org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.3.2'
> ```

i have the train data in assets.

my source code if the main activity is following:

```
package mr.t.mister.mr;


        import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import org.bytedeco.javacpp.lept.PIX;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.tesseract.TessBaseAPI;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.lept.pixRead;
//import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;

public class SimpleAndroidOCRActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple";
    public static final String DATA_PATH = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/SimpleAndroidOCR/";

    // You should have the trained data file in assets folder
    // You can get them at:
    // https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata
    public static final String lang = "eng";

    private static final String TAG = "SimpleAndroidOCR.java";

    protected Button _button;
    // protected ImageView _image;
    protected EditText _field;
    protected String _path;
    protected boolean _taken;

    protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "photo_taken";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String[] paths = new String[] { DATA_PATH, DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" };

        for (String path : paths) {
            File dir = new File(path);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "ERROR: Creation of directory " + path + " on sdcard failed");
                    return;
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Created directory " + path + " on sdcard");
                }
            }

        }

        // lang.traineddata file with the app (in assets folder)
        // You can get them at:
        // http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list
        // This area needs work and optimization
        if (!(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata")).exists()) {
            try {

                AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata");
                //GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DATA_PATH
                        + "tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata");

                // Transfer bytes from in to out
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                //while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                //gin.close();
                out.close();

                Log.v(TAG, "Copied " + lang + " traineddata");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy " + lang + " traineddata " + e.toString());
            }
        }



        // _image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        _field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field);
        _button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        _button.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());

        _path = DATA_PATH + "/ocr.jpg";
    }

    public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Starting Camera app");
            startCameraActivity();
        }
    }

    // Simple android photo capture:
    // http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/simple-android-photo-capture/

    protected void startCameraActivity() {
        File file = new File(_path);
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Log.i(TAG, "resultCode: " + resultCode);

        if (resultCode == -1) {
            onPhotoTaken();
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "User cancelled");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState()");
        if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN)) {
            onPhotoTaken();
        }
    }

    protected void onPhotoTaken() {
        _taken = true;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path, options);

        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(_path);
            int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            Log.v(TAG, "Orient: " + exifOrientation);

            int rotate = 0;

            switch (exifOrientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotate = 90;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotate = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotate = 270;
                    break;
            }

            Log.v(TAG, "Rotation: " + rotate);

            if (rotate != 0) {

                // Getting width & height of the given image.
                int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                int h = bitmap.getHeight();

                // Setting pre rotate
                Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                mtx.preRotate(rotate);

                // Rotating Bitmap
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
            }

            // Convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
            bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't correct orientation: " + e.toString());
        }

        // _image.setImageBitmap( bitmap );

        Log.v(TAG, "Before baseApi");

        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
        //baseApi.setDebug(true);


        //baseApi.Init()
        baseApi.Init(DATA_PATH, lang);

        PIX image = pixRead(_path);
        //PIX image = pixRead(args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "/usr/src/tesseract/testing/phototest.tif");
        baseApi.SetImage(image);

        String recognizedText = baseApi.GetUTF8Text().getString(); //baseApi.getUTF8Text();

        baseApi.End();

        // You now have the text in recognizedText var, you can do anything with it.
        // We will display a stripped out trimmed alpha-numeric version of it (if lang is eng)
        // so that garbage doesn't make it to the display.

        Log.v(TAG, "OCRED TEXT: " + recognizedText);

        if ( lang.equalsIgnoreCase("eng") ) {
            recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ");
        }

        recognizedText = recognizedText.trim();

        if ( recognizedText.length() != 0 ) {
            _field.setText(_field.getText().toString().length() == 0 ? recognizedText : _field.getText() + " " + recognizedText);
            _field.setSelection(_field.getText().toString().length());
        }

        // Cycle done.
    }

    // www.Gaut.am was here
    // Thanks for reading!
}
```

when i try to start tesseract, App crashes. i get following things:

```
05-09 20:18:09.187 26906-26906/mr.t.mister.mr E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: mr.t.mister.mr, PID: 26906
                                                                java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libjnilept.so"
                                                                    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
                                                                    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
                                                                    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:963)
                                                                    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:764)
                                                                    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:671)
                                                                    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.lept.<clinit>(lept.java:10)
                                                                    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
                                                                    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:726)
                                                                    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:671)
                                                                    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tesseract$TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(tesseract.java:3648)
                                                                    at mr.t.mister.mr.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onPhotoTaken(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:214)
                                                                    at mr.t.mister.mr.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onActivityResult(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:138)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6192)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3570)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mr.t.mister.mr-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "liblept.so"
                                                                    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
                                                                    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
                                                                    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:963)
                                                                    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:752)
                                                                    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:671) 
                                                                    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.lept.<clinit>(lept.java:10) 
                                                                    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309) 
                                                                    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:726) 
                                                                    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:671) 
                                                                    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tesseract$TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(tesseract.java:3648) 
                                                                    at mr.t.mister.mr.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onPhotoTaken(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:214) 
                                                                    at mr.t.mister.mr.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onActivityResult(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:138) 
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6192) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3570) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
05-09 20:18:09.282 26906-26919/mr.t.mister.mr I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 798(72KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(91KB) LOS objects, 41% free, 1438KB/2MB, paused 14.815ms total 39.575ms
```

Comment: As-is, this question does not relate to `tess-two`. If you want to use tess-two, you should follow the [usage instructions](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two#usage) to add the dependency in your `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

Unsatisfied link error is produced when Android is not able to obtain a .so library.

Make sure that all your .so are under in their corresponding folder. One or several of the followings -> https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html?hl=es

```
src
---main
------java
---------jnilibs
------------armeabi 
------------arm64-v8a
------------...
```

It is possible you experiment the problem also if your device's processor does not match one of the abi you defined.

You can force your app to use a defined set of abis modifying build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    ....
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi', 'arm64-v8a'
}
```

Comment: #jDur  
i have added the library in gradle file like compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:tesseract:3.04.01-1.3'. so i dont have any *.so file!! what to do now? please suggest!!

Comment: is your tesseract version compiled for android? if so, check that you have the libraries needed by tesseract. Here in the docs it says "Simply put all the desired JAR files (opencv*.jar, ffmpeg*.jar, etc.), in addition to javacpp.jar, somewhere in your class path. The JAR files available as pre-built artifacts are meant to be used with JavaCPP". https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue. When I included all the dependencies as below using *, it vanished.

```
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.*;
import org.bytedeco.leptonica.*;
import org.bytedeco.tesseract.*;
import static org.bytedeco.leptonica.global.lept.*;
import static org.bytedeco.tesseract.global.tesseract.*;
```